# How do I display explanation for Option 1 in Angular quiz app?

Tags: angular

I'm working on a quiz app using Angular and I need the explanation text to also display when the first option is selected (the explanation displays for all of the options but the first option). When Option 1 is selected, the explanation, even if there isn't any, changes back to the question. Also for question 1 (multiple choice), the incorrect sound plays when Option 1 is selected, but the answer is correct.

snippet of code in di-quiz.component.html where explanationText appears:

```
<mat-card-content>
  <scoreboard></scoreboard>

  <section id="question" [class.answered]="answer">
    <span *ngIf="!answer">{{ question?.questionText }}&nbsp;
      <span *ngIf="numberOfCorrectOptions > 1">
        <em>({{ numberOfCorrectOptions }} options are correct)</em>
      </span>
    </span>
    <span *ngIf="answer">{{ explanationText }}</span>
  </section>

  <quiz-question
    [question]="question"
    (answer)="selectedAnswer($event)">
  </quiz-question>
</mat-card-content>
```

Please see my StackBlitz here: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app**

I'd appreciate your help with fixing these bugs. Thank you.

Comment: I would be great if you provided a link to stackblitz example

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app

Comment: Please can you help with this issue. Thank you.

Comment: FYI, this issue has been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62314855/angular-display-quiz-results-correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next question does not appear because you don't reset `answer` property and `*ngIf="!answer"` is always `true`.

Try to reset it once you move to the next/previous question:

```
nextQuestion() {
  this.answer = null;
  this.checkIfAnsweredCorrectly();
  this.quizService.nextQuestion();
}

prevQuestion() {
  this.answer = null;
  this.quizService.prevQuestion();
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app-3lofn6?file=src/app/containers/dependency-injection-quiz/dependency-injection-quiz.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks. I've added the null assignment and the question resets. I would like it so that whenever any option is selected the explanation text shows.

Comment: It seems that the explanation text displays for all but the first option for each question.