# Why are my quiz results not displaying correctly?

Tags: angular

I am working on a quiz ResultsComponent using Angular 9, but having difficulty getting the results to display correctly in the mat-accordion with the data. I have a userAnswers array, correctAnswers array and a quizData.ts external file containing the quizData array object, and I am showing a summary of the results to the user, specifically "Your Answer(s)", "Correct Answer(s)", "Explanation" and "Elapsed Time" for each question in the quiz.

In testing the app, the user answer option number(s) sometimes do not seem to correspond with the correct option text; the same goes for the correct answers. In the multiple choice questions, options should be displayed as "1 and 2", not "1, 2" in the correct answers and explanation. I've passed the correct options string (with "1 and 2") to the ResultsComponent, but it should probably be an array of strings of correct options in case of several M/C questions. Also in testing, sometimes when the user answer and correct answer are different, the correct checkmark is shown, even when the user answer is not correct.

I am sharing a snippet of the code below, but you can view the entire quiz here: **http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app**. I would appreciate your help with these issues. Thank you.

EDIT: I need to use the Results model so that I can have:

```
{
answer: [1,2],
time: 18
},
{
answer: [4],
time: 2
},
...
```

and **use Results in the template instead of using userAnswers and elapsedTimes**

```
<section class="quizSummary">
  <details>
    <summary i18n>Click to view a more detailed summary of your quiz</summary>

      <mat-accordion [multi]="true" #accordion="matAccordion">
        <mat-expansion-panel
          class="quiz-summary-question"
          *ngFor="let question of quizData.questions; let i = index"
          (opened)="panelOpenState = true" (closed)="panelOpenState = false" hideToggle="true">

          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-description>
              <mat-icon class="accordion-icon" *ngIf="!panelOpenState">add</mat-icon>
              <mat-icon class="accordion-icon" *ngIf="panelOpenState">remove</mat-icon>
            </mat-panel-description>

             <mat-panel-title>
               <span class="question-leader" i18n>Question #{{ i + 1 }}: </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
               <span class="question-text" i18n>{{ question?.questionText }}</span>
             </mat-panel-title>

             <ng-template
                matExpansionPanelContent>
                <ul class="quiz-summary-fields" *ngIf="correctAnswers[i].length > 1">
                  <li i18n>
                    <span class="leader">Your Answer: </span>
                    Option {{ userAnswers[i] }} &mdash; {{ question?.options[i].text }}
                    <mat-icon class="correct"
                              *ngIf="checkIfAnswersAreCorrect(correctAnswers, userAnswers)">done</mat-icon>
                    <mat-icon class="incorrect"
                              *ngIf="!checkIfAnswersAreCorrect(correctAnswers, userAnswers)">clear</mat-icon>
                    <span *ngIf="userAnswers[i] === null"> (no answer provided)</span>
                  </li>
                  <li i18n>
                    <span class="leader">Correct Answer(s): </span>
                    <span *ngIf="correctAnswers[i].length === 1">
                      Option {{ correctAnswers[i] }} &mdash; {{ question?.options[i].text }}
                    </span>
                    <span *ngIf="correctAnswers[i].length > 1">
                      Options {{ correctAnswers[i] }} &mdash; {{ question?.options[i].text }}
                    </span>
                  </li>
                  <li i18n>
                    <span class="leader">Explanation: </span>
                    <span *ngIf="correctAnswers[i].length === 1">
                      Option {{ correctAnswers[i] }} was correct because {{ question?.explanation }}.
                    </span>
                    <span *ngIf="correctAnswers[i].length > 1">
                      Options {{ correctAnswers[i] }} were correct because {{ question?.explanation }}.
                    </span>
                  </li>
                  <li i18n>
                    <span class="leader">Elapsed Time: </span>
                    <span>{{ elapsedTimes[i] }} second</span>
                  </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="quiz-summary-fields" *ngIf="correctAnswers[i].length === 1">
                  <li i18n>
                    <span class="leader">Your Answer: </span>
                    Option {{ userAnswers[i] }} &mdash; {{ question?.options[i].text }}
                    <mat-icon class="correct"
                              *ngIf="checkIfAnswersAreCorrect(correctAnswers, userAnswers)">done</mat-icon>
                    <mat-icon class="incorrect"
                              *ngIf="!checkIfAnswersAreCorrect(correctAnswers, userAnswers)">clear</mat-icon>
                    <span *ngIf="userAnswers[i] === null"> (no answer provided)</span>
                  </li>
                  <li i18n>
                    <span class="leader">Correct Answer(s): </span>
                    <span *ngIf="correctAnswers[i].length === 1">
                      Option {{ correctAnswers[i] }} &mdash; {{ question?.options[i].text }}
                    </span>
                    <span *ngIf="correctAnswers[i].length > 1">
                      Options {{ correctAnswers[i] }} &mdash; {{ question?.options[i].text }}
                    </span>
                  </li>
                  <li i18n>
                    <span class="leader">Explanation: </span>
                    <span *ngIf="correctAnswers[i].length === 1">
                      Option {{ correctAnswers[i] }} was correct because {{ question?.explanation }}.
                    </span>
                    <span *ngIf="correctAnswers[i].length > 1">
                      Options {{ correctAnswers[i] }} were correct because {{ question?.explanation }}.
                    </span>
                  </li>
                  <li i18n>
                    <span class="leader">Elapsed Time: </span>
                    <span>{{ elapsedTimes[i] }} seconds</span>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </ng-template>
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          </mat-expansion-panel>
        </mat-accordion>
...
```

in results.component.ts:

```
checkIfAnswersAreCorrect(correctAnswers: [], userAnswers: []) {
  const resultsComparisonArray = new Array();

  for (let i = 0; i < correctAnswers.length; i++) {
    resultsComparisonArray.push(correctAnswers[i] === userAnswers[i] ? true : false);
  }

  return resultsComparisonArray;
}
```

Test 1:
If I enter 2,4,2,3 for question 1,2,3,4

in question 3, Option 2 - function, should be constructor

in question 4, Option 3 - Declare an object, should be mark as Injectable()

[image: test 1 - all correct answers: 2,4,2,3]

---

Test 2: entering 1,1,1,1

in question 2 - should have an x instead of checkmark, explanation should show "1 and 2"

```
           Option 1 - Testability, should be Programming

           Option 4 - Testabliity, should be All of the above
```

in question 3, Option 1 - should be Injectable()

```
           Option 2 - should be constructor
```

in question 4, Option 1 - Declare an object, should be Require in the component

```
           Option 3 - Declare an object, should be Mark as Injectable()
```

and number of elapsed seconds not shown

[image: test 2 - questions 2,3]
[image: test 2 - question 4]

---

Test 3: entering 4,4,4,4

in question 1 - Option 1 - Pass service to the client, should be Give the client part service, should have x instead of checkmark

in question 2 - Option 4 - Testability, should be All of the above

in question 3 - Option 4 - function, should be NgModule, should have x instead of checkmark

in question 4 - Option 3 - Declare an object, should be Mark dependency as Injectable()

number of elapsed seconds not shown

### [image: case 3 - questions 1,2]
[image: case 3 - questions 3,4]

Comment: What is the problem you are looking to fix? "1 and 2" is correctly displayed. What does: "the user answers doesn't seem to sometimes correspond with the correct option" means? Sometimes isnt good enough, do you have a specific way to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I updated my question with test cases and expected output.

Comment: I think you are over-complicating things by using lots of indexes there, it gets harder to read the code, just use the object references for you operations, things would get a lot easier whilst debugging.

Comment: I tried without indexes using "*ngFor=let userAnswer of userAnswers; let correctAnswer of correctAnswers" etc. but wasn't getting the correct output for the correct answers.

Comment: Is your problem about checmarks ?

Comment: Yes that's part of it.

Comment: Please can someone help to finish the ResultsComponent - the problem with the correct option text not displaying and another issue that the "1 and 2" is showing for all answer messages.

Comment: @integral100x please check my solution below.

Comment: Thank you both, but I'm still getting 1 and 2 for all answers in quiz and I'm having some undesirable output in mat-accordion in these tests:
In ALL tests in q2,3,4 Options should be Option in both corr answer and expl, expl should use 'was'
In tests using 1,1,1,1 and 4,4,4,4: elapsedTime not showing in q4
I'm not sure why leader text is on its own line.
I would like to use Result interface explained in my edit and eliminate userAnswers and elapsedTimes in the quiz; it would get it from the Results object.
I was trying to use quizMetadata object but having trouble initializing object.

Comment: I posted in the chat below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results.html was using wrong indexes. It should be :-

```
  <section class="quizSummary">
    <details>
      <summary i18n>Click to view a more detailed summary of your quiz&hellip;</summary>

      <mat-accordion [multi]="true" #accordion="matAccordion">
        <mat-expansion-panel
          class="quiz-summary-question"
          *ngFor="let question of quizData.questions; let i = index"
          (opened)="panelOpenState = true" (closed)="panelOpenState = false" hideToggle="true">

          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-description>
              <mat-icon class="accordion-icon" *ngIf="!panelOpenState">add</mat-icon>
              <mat-icon class="accordion-icon" *ngIf="panelOpenState">remove</mat-icon>
            </mat-panel-description>

            <mat-panel-title>
              <span class="question-leader" i18n>Question #{{ i + 1 }}: </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <span class="question-text" i18n>{{ question?.questionText }}</span>
            </mat-panel-title>

            <ng-template
              matExpansionPanelContent>
              <ul class="quiz-summary-fields" *ngIf="correctAnswers.length >= 1">
                <li i18n>
                  <span class="leader">Your Answer(s):</span>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="results?.userAnswers[i]">
                    Option {{ results.userAnswers[i] | join }} &mdash;
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of results?.userAnswers[i]; let isLast = last">
                      {{ question?.options[item - 1].text }} <span *ngIf="!isLast"> AND </span>
                    </ng-container>
                    <mat-icon class="correct"
                      *ngIf="checkIfAnswersAreCorrect(correctAnswers, results?.userAnswers, i)">done</mat-icon>
                    <mat-icon class="incorrect"
                      *ngIf="!checkIfAnswersAreCorrect(correctAnswers, results?.userAnswers, i)">clear</mat-icon>
                  </ng-container>
                  <span *ngIf="!results?.userAnswers[i] || results?.userAnswers.length === 0">
                    (no answer provided)
                  </span>
                </li>
                <li i18n>
                  <span class="leader">Correct Answer(s):</span>
                  <span *ngIf="correctAnswers.length === 1">
                    Option {{ correctAnswers[i] }} &mdash; {{ question?.options[i].text }}
                  </span>
                  <span *ngIf="correctAnswers.length > 1">
                    Options {{ correctAnswers[i][0] | join }} &mdash;
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of correctAnswers[i][0]; let isLast = last">
                      {{ question?.options[item - 1].text }} <span *ngIf="!isLast"> AND </span>
                    </ng-container>
                  </span>
                </li>
                <li i18n>
                  <span class="leader">Explanation:</span>
                  <span *ngIf="correctAnswers[i][0].length === 1">
                    Option {{ correctAnswers[i] }} was correct because {{ question?.explanation }}.
                  </span>
                  <span *ngIf="correctAnswers[i][0].length > 1">
                    Options {{ correctAnswers[i][0] | join }} were correct because {{ question?.explanation }}.
                  </span>
                </li>
                <li i18n>
                  <span class="leader">Elapsed Time:</span>
                  <span>{{ results.elapsedTimes[i] }} seconds</span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </ng-template>
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
      </mat-accordion>
      <mat-action-row class="mat-accordion-buttons">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openAllPanels()">
          <strong>Expand All</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<mat-icon>unfold_more</mat-icon>
        </button> &nbsp;
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="closeAllPanels()">
          <strong>Collapse All</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<mat-icon>unfold_less</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-action-row>
    </details>
  </section>
```

For showing and instead of , in options i created a join pipe like below :-

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'join'
})
export class JoinPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    console.log(value);
    return value.join(" and ")
  }

}
```

For No Answers provided issue and option was issue :- i updated the template above and with that  in dependency-injection-quiz.component.ts checkIfAnswersCorrectly() Method i changed :-

```
this.quizService.userAnswers.push(this.answer + 1);
```

to

```
this.quizService.userAnswers.push(this.answer ? this.answer + 1 : this.answer);
```

For no elapsed time in question 4 in some cases, in dependency-injection-quiz.component.ts results() method i added :-

```
this.quizService.resetAll();
```

For QuizMetaData Issue, you want to make all fields optional. So I initialized it like :-

```
quizMetadata: Partial<QuizMetadata> = {};
```

For knowing about Partial you can check  :- https://medium.com/dev-genius/crafting-perfect-interface-for-a-crud-in-angular-with-utility-types-44873e516a1e

For fixing showing correct answer when selected i moved :-

```
this.correctMessage = this.quizService.correctMessage;
```

from ngOnInit to setSelected method.

For leader text in same line in result.component.css i changed your leader class from :-

```
.leader {
              font-weight: $font-weight-max;
             
            }
```

to

```
.leader {
              font-weight: $font-weight-max;
              display: inline;
            }
```

For Reset Issue added resetQuestions Method to quiz service :-

```
  resetQuestions() {
    this.quizData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(QUIZ_DATA));
  }
```

and called it in restart method :-

```
  restart() {
    this.quizService.resetAll();
    this.quizService.resetQuestions();
    this.timerService.elapsedTimes = [];
    this.timerService.completionTime = 0;
    this.router.navigate(['/intro']);
  }
```

and changed the initialization of quizdata to :-

```
quizData: Quiz = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(QUIZ_DATA));
```

For incorrect sound and not able to select multiple answers, changed your setSelected method in question.component.ts to :-

```
setSelected(optionIndex: number): void {
    this.quizStarted = true;
    this.correctMessage = this.quizService.correctMessage;
    this.isCorrectAnswerSelected = this.isCorrect(this.currentQuestion.options[optionIndex].correct, optionIndex);
    this.answer.emit(optionIndex);
    if(this.correctAnswers.length == 1) {
        this.currentQuestion.options.forEach(o => o.selected = false);
    }
    this.currentQuestion.options[optionIndex].selected = true;
    if (
      optionIndex >= 0 &&
      this.currentQuestion &&
      this.currentQuestion.options &&
      this.currentQuestion.options[optionIndex]['correct']
    ) {
      this.timerService.stopTimer();
      this.quizService.correctSound.play();
      optionIndex = null;
    } else {
      console.log('In else');
      this.quizService.incorrectSound.play();
    }

    this.alreadyAnswered = true;
  }
```

For pushing multiple answers changed following things into dependency-injection-quiz.component.ts :-

```
answer: number[] = [];
nextQuestion() {
    this.checkIfAnsweredCorrectly();
    this.answer = [];
    this.animationState$.next('animationStarted');
    this.quizService.nextQuestion();
  }


selectedAnswer(data) {
    const correctAnswers = this.question.options.filter((options) => options.correct);
    if(correctAnswers.length > 1 && this.answer.indexOf(data) === -1) {
         this.answer.push(data);
    } else {
      this.answer[0] = data;
    }
  }
```

and in result.component.ts :-

```
checkIfAnswersAreCorrect(correctAnswers, userAnswers,index:number): boolean {
    return !(!userAnswers[index] || userAnswers[index].length ===0 || userAnswers[index].find((ans) => correctAnswers[index][0].indexOf(ans) === -1));
  }
```

For Incorrect Sound

For No Question Displayed In dependency-injection-quiz.component.html:-

from :-

```
<section id="question" [class.answered]="answer">
      <span *ngIf="!answer" i18n>{{ question?.questionText }}&nbsp;
        <span *ngIf="numberOfCorrectOptions > 1">
          <em>({{ numberOfCorrectOptions }} options are correct.)</em>
        </span>
      </span>
      <span *ngIf="answer" i18n>{{ explanationText }}</span>
    </section>
```

to

```
<section id="question" [class.answered]="answer">
  <span *ngIf="!answer || answer.length === 0" i18n>{{ question?.questionText }}&nbsp;
    <span *ngIf="numberOfCorrectOptions > 1">
      <em>({{ numberOfCorrectOptions }} options are correct.)</em>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span *ngIf="answer && answer.length > 0" i18n>{{ explanationText }}</span>
</section>
```

Working Stackblitz :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app-tmgqor

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216658/discussion-on-answer-by-aakash-garg-angular-display-quiz-results-correctly).

Comment: I posted in the chat.

Comment: In question 2, if the next button is clicked and no answer is selected then in question 3 I am getting Options 1 and 2 as correct when it should only be Option 2 - constructor. ALSO in the Correct Answers field in mat-accordion in ResultsComponent, I am still seeing "Options" for single-answer questions.

Answer (score 4):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app-wzbv7m)

You should also send index in function to avoid loop and then  first array includes two nested array then in function will work correct for markings

```
checkIfAnswersAreCorrect(correctAnswers, userAnswers,index:number): boolean {
    return  correctAnswers[index][0].indexOf(userAnswers[index])>-1 ? true : false;
}
```

In html

```
<mat-icon class="correct" *ngIf="checkIfAnswersAreCorrect(correctAnswers, userAnswers,i)">done</mat-icon>
```

You don't need if condition for correct answer label, both of label are same in both condition. Your missing is that you should take correct answer's option rather than directly question's option

```
<li i18n>
   <span class="leader">Correct Answer(s): </span>   
   <span> Options {{ correctAnswers[i] }} &mdash; {{question?.options[correctAnswers[i][0][0]-1].text }} </span>
</li>
```

[Demo with correct label](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app-n29xnx)

Comment: Thank you, but I have spotted some errors in testing: correctMessages text seems to have changed, it's 1 and 2 all the time now for all questions in the quiz. Wanted 1,2 in ResultsComponent to display as "1 and 2".

In ResultsComponent:
Test 1: 1,4,2,3
q3 text should be constructor
q4 should be @Injectable()

Test 2: 4,4,4,4
q2 Testability, should be all of the above
q3
your ans: Opt. 4 - function, should be NgModule
corr ans: Opt. 2 - function, should be constructor
q4
corr ans: Opt 3 - Declare an object, should be @Injectable()
# of seconds not shown

Comment: Test 3: 1,1,1,1
q2
user ans: Option 1 - Testability, should be Programming
corr ans: Option 4 - Testability, should be All of the above
q3 
user ans: Option 1 - function should be @Injectable()
corr ans: Option 2 - function should be constructor

q4
user ans: Opt 2 - declare an object should be Provide in the module
corr ans: Opt 3 - declare an object should be Mark dependency as Injectable()
# of seconds not shown

Comment: If I don't give an answer, I get 'Option NaN - Pass the service to the client.', should say '(no answer provided)'

Comment: Please could you help with getting the correct option text displaying correctly, and "1 and 2" seems to be displaying for all the answers in the quiz.

Comment: I would like to use the Result model as shown in my edit above instead of using userAnswers and elapsedTimes in the template.

Comment: I updated your code with correct label your missing was you were directly getting option but you should take correct answer option https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app-n29xnx  @integral100x I putted console.log to component ts to show how correctanswer architecture like. so you can understand why I wrote [0][0]